# "else" statement executed before "if" statement after `undo` is used in Python

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, turtle-graphics, undo

I have created the following function that allows the user to change the shape of the Python turtle to an image he/she selects from a file dialog file dialog that pops up when a specific button is pressed:

```
def TurtleShape(iop = None):
   # "iop" is supposed to be an image path
   try:
       manipulateimage.config(state = NORMAL)
       flipButton.config(state = NORMAL)
       mirrorButton.config(state = NORMAL)
       originalButton.config(state = NORMAL)
       resetturtle.config(state = NORMAL)
       rotateButton.config(state = NORMAL)
       global klob
       # The following "if-else" statement uses the "iop" argument's value as the value for "klob" if `iop` is NOT `None`
       if iop != None:
           klob = iop
           print("lmcv")
       else:
           klob = filedialog.askopenfilename()
           print("klobby")
       global im
       im = Image.open(klob)
       pictures.append(im)
       edited.clear()
       print(im)
       im.save(klob + '.gif', "GIF")
       register_shape(klob + '.gif')
       shape(klob + '.gif')
       update()
   except:
       pass
```

The above function is also supposed to use the `iop` argument's value as the turtle's image if it is not `None`.

Now, consider this situation; you draw a bunch of things, set the turtle to an image, and just when you are about to stamp the image, **you accidentally press the button that resets the turtle to its normal shape (yes, that button exists in my program).** Oh no! How would you get it back without going through all the steps to open and edit it again? Well, that is where my undoHandler function (shown below) comes in. It just essentially undoes the last function called using many stacks, which I created as `deque`s. It is pretty straightforward if you are proficient in Python:

```
def undoHandler():
   if len(function) > 0 and draw.drawing == True:
      undoHandler.handling = True
      if not hasattr(undoHandler, "counter"):
         undoHandler.counter = 0
      undoHandler.counter += 1
      # clear the canvas
      Clear()
      # Pop a point object from function deque
      function.pop()
      penup()
      goto(-200, 100)
      pendown()

      try:
          # Execute everything up to point before last function called
          for i in function:
             # Set canvas and turtle to previous state
             tsd = i.recieveshape()
             shape(tsd)
             mndf = i.recieveheading()
             setheading(mndf)
             hk = i.getletterheight()
             global letter_height 
             letter_height = hk
             rk = i.getletterwidth()
             global letter_width
             letter_width = rk
             milk = i.getspacewidth()
             global space_width
             space_width = milk
             hw = i.getwidth()
             width(hw)
             op = i.getcolor()
             try:
                color(op)
             except:
                for g in colors:
                   cp = g.getcolor2()
                   colormode(255)
                   color(cp)
             # Get function wrapped in Point object and execute it
             j = i.getfunction()
             j()
             # Following is the code block where the issue occurs. Basically, if the function being run is equal to `TurtleShape`, then do the following...
             if j.__name__ == "TurtleShape":
                 # `hfl` is a deque that holds all of the `pictures` deque's contents as it is cleared when the turtle is set to its default state
                 pictures.extend(hfl)
                 lmcv = pictures.pop()
                 pictures.append(lmcv)
                 try:
                     # Resize image to previous size if user changes it. Otherwise, skip this.
                     bun = picwidth.pop()
                     picwidth.append(bun)
                     mun = picheight.pop()
                     picheight.append(mun)
                     clob = lmcv.resize((int(bun), int(mun)), Image.ANTIALIAS)
                 except:
                     clob = lmcv
                 clob.save(klob + str(undoHandler.counter) + ".gif")
                 # Use the `clob.save` output from above as source image in `TurtleShape` function (this is where issue occurs)
                 TurtleShape(klob + str(undoHandler.counter) + ".gif")
                 print("Undone!")
             else:
                 pass
      except:
         pass
```

Basically what happens here is that it takes the function (wrapped in a `Point` object) from a queue through which the main functions go through as they are called. The functions then get appended to the `function` deque, after which, when `undoHandler` is called by the user, the screen gets cleared, and latest value is popped from the `function` deque so that all the other actions **except** the last one will be executed again. This issue I am facing occurs specifically in the `if j.__name__ == "TurtleShape":` code block. Basically, for some reason, when the user chooses to undo the resetting of the turtle to its original shape, it works as it should **until** the `TurtleShape` function is executed by the undoHandler. **For some reason, when the undoHandler executes the `TurtleShape` function, even when I give a valid argument for the `iop` attribute of the `TurtleShape` function (as you can see in the `if j.__name__ == "TurtleShape":` code block), the `else` statement is executed *first* (i.e. the file dialog comes up instead of continuing from the `if` statement). Only if the user clicks `cancel` in that dialog will the turtle get set to the previous image.**

***What is wrong in my code that is leading to this occurrence, and how would I stop this from happening?*** I have tried changing the `klob` attribute in the function where the output is saved in the `undoHandler` function to, for example, `"SaveImage"`, but still no luck. I have also tried to add an `if-elif` statement in the `TurtleShape` when it is supposed to choose between `iop` or a file dialog as the value for `klob`, but still the issue occurs. Apparently, it executes the `elif` statement *even when it is not necessarily true.* **Therefore, any help is very much appreciated in remedying this issue! :)**

Comment: Difficult to see the forest for the trees: could you follow http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Maybe you should give the minimal related code and explanation about your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's happening here:

```
         j = i.getfunction()
         j()
```

If the function you've just gotten is the `TurtleShape()` function, then you're calling it once with its default arguments (i.e., `iop = None`). Then you go into your big `if j.__name__ == "TurtleShape":` statement and call it again inside the `if` block.

Move that `j()` call into the `else:` block of your big `if j.__name__ == "TurtleShape":` statement, and your problem should go away.

Does that brief explanation make enough sense for you to understand ***why*** the problem is happening? Or do you need me to explain a bit more in-depth how calling `j()` is calling `TurtleShape` with the parameter `iop = None`?

Comment: Yeah, I can see why that is happening. I was stupid not to think of it earlier. It works perfectly now, and thank you for your help! Maybe I should hire you for helping me in my project ;) ...just kidding. I couldn't pay you if I wanted to since I am just a teen dependent on my parents for money...anyways, thanks again! :)